# What is the default cache refresh time of InternetOpenURL?

Tags: delphi, wininet

One of my programs uses InternetOpenURL without the INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD specified.  I see that the call will read the web page from the cache (if it exists).  I changed the web page 5 days ago and I still get the cached version (unless I specify the flag above.)   Does anyone know when or if the cache will ever be updated?  I'd expect it to eventually be refreshed (possibly overly optimistic!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the original resource had an expiration date on it that is more than 5 days, that is why the cached version keeps being used if you do not tell `InternetOpenURL()` to re-check the server once in awhile.  However, `INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD` forces it to re-download the resource whether it has actually been modified or not.  That might be a little too brute force for your needs.  Try using `INTERNET_FLAG_RESYNCHRONIZE` instead.  That allows `InternetOpenURL()` to check if the resource has been modified and then re-download it only if needed, otherwise keep using the cached copy.

Comment: Thanks Remy, the note about RESYNCHRONIZE is appreciated.  Is there a way to determine the expiration date for the cached page?  Is it something that's set by the web server?  I've searched and didn't seem to find any information about it.  Basically I want to know if the new version will ever be picked up my my InternetOpenURL call that has no flags set.

Comment: Cache management and expiration can be set by the web server, yes. Check the resonse headers. Eventually, InternetOpenURL() should recheck the original resource, though it is a good idea to force it once in awhile, just in case.